# Group by the maximum date and return the text from each grouped record

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return the row with the maxium date for every person, how can I filter this

1. **Initials, Date, Text**
2. DD, 1/1/2022, 123
3. DD, 1/1/2021, 456
4. DD, 1/1/2020, 789
5. KT, 1/1/2020, abc
6. KT, 1/1/2022, def
7. KT, 1/2/2021, ghi

so the results appear like this?

1. **Initials, Date, Text**
2. DD, 1/1/2022, 123
3. KT, 1/1/2022, def

I've tried the MAX date and grouping by the initials, but I am trying to return the text from the entry with the maximum date.

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing it.

DDL (I used a temp table for testing purposes):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp;

CREATE TABLE #tmp (
    initials varchar(10),
    date date,
    text varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #tmp
VALUES
    ('DD', '2022-01-01', '123'),
    ('DD', '2021-01-01', '456'),
    ('DD', '2020-01-01', '789'),
    ('KT', '2020-01-01', 'abc'),
    ('KT', '2022-01-01', '123'),
    ('KT', '2021-01-02', 'ghi');
```

Version 1 (Subquery with `MAX`):
This version pulls unique initials and their MAX date, then links back to the original table on those initials and date to pull the text from the record.

```
SELECT t.initials, t.date, t.text
FROM #tmp AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT initials, MAX(date) AS max_date
    FROM #tmp
    GROUP BY initials
) AS sub
    ON t.initials = sub.initials
    AND t.date = sub.max_date
```

Version 2 (Subquery with `ROW_NUMBER`):
This version uses the window function ROW_NUMBER to number each row ordered by date descending. This will give the most recent date a row number of 1. Then pull the text from the records with row number = 1.

```
SELECT sub.initials, sub.date, sub.text
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY initials ORDER BY date DESC) AS row_num
    FROM #tmp
) AS sub
WHERE sub.row_num = 1
```

Since the text for both initials in your sample set on the max date are the same, I added initials and date to the final result set for clarification.

You can also use CTEs instead of subqueries, which I prefer, but I didn't want to complicate matters.